# Determine JSON Structure with Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have have a table in a database, one column of which includes some JSON.

In each row the individual JSON will be slightly different. Each will include some of the attributes of the JSON, but none will include them all. For example

```
{
    "testAssignmentName": "RhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarb"
}
```

and

```
{
    "testSkill": {
        "testProfileId": 72,
        "educationalLevelId": 11
    },
    "primaryPooltrial": {
        "mainTestSkill": {
            "testSkill": {
                "testProfileId": 72,
                "educationalLevelId": 11
            },
            "trialDefinition": {
                "trial": 99.0,
                "trialFrequencyId": 1
            }
        },
        "additionalTestSkills": [],
        "results": [{
                "resultTypeId": 4,
                "resultAmount": 20.0,
                "resultFrequencyId": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "requirements": "RhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarb"
}
```

and

```
{
    "requirements": "RhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarb",
    "testSkill": {
        "testProfileId": 21,
        "educationalLevelId": 17
    },
    "primaryPooltrial": {
        "mainTestSkill": {
            "testSkill": {
                "testProfileId": 21,
                "educationalLevelId": 17
            }
        },
        "results": []
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "testAssignmentName": "Rhubarb Rhubarb Rhubarb Rhubarb Rhubarb Rhubarb ",
    "requirements": "RhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarb"
}
```

Is there one piece of code that will allow me to extract the overall structure so I can parse the JSON without missing any of the attributes in a later part of the code?

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you need. If you just pass all these as-is, then you're not missing anything later.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for responding. What I am trying to get is a single list of all the attributes, including their heirarchy. There may be a bunch of attributes in other json strings I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
import json

jsonstring = """{
            "requirements": "RhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarb",
            "testSkill": {
                "testProfileId": 21,
                "educationalLevelId": 17
            },
            "primaryPooltrial": {
                "mainTestSkill": {
                    "testSkill": {
                        "testProfileId": 21,
                        "educationalLevelId": 17
                    }
                },
                "results": []
            }
        }"""

data = json.loads(jsonstring)
print (data)
```

This will have the following results:

```
{'requirements': 'RhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarb', 'primaryPooltrial': {'mainTestSkill': {'testSkill': {'educationalLevelId': 17, 'testProfileId': 21}}, 'results': []}, 'testSkill': {'educationalLevelId': 17, 'testProfileId': 21}}
```

You can also select with:

```
print (data["requirements"])
```

And get the following:

```
RhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarbRhubarb
```